# $rootScope.on is calling twice before destroy in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-rootscope

In this issue, first time it is coming into else block where **downloadCsv** method is getting called then rather destroy the component is again comes into **if block**. Somehow subscription has made twice in this method. How can we reduce that?
**Is there any way in rootscope to identify the number of request?**

```
public $onInit() {
if (
      this.type === CsvDownloadTypes.ANY ||
      this.type === CsvDownloadTypes.GLOBAL_USER ||
      this.type === CsvDownloadTypes.USER
    ) {
      const listener =  this.$rootScope.$on('csv-download-request', (_event, options) => {
        console.log("event..",_event);

          this.FILENAME = options.filename || this.FILENAME;
          if (this.CsvDownloadService.downloadInProgress) {
            console.log("if block");
            this.Notification.error('csvDownload.isRunning');
          } else {
            // start export
            console.log("else block");
            this.downloadCsv(options.csvType);
          }
        });
        this.eventListeners.push(listener);
        console.log("scopr..", angular.element().scope)
        console.log("scope 2..", this.$rootScope);
    }

    // see if there is a current active download, and set out flag
    this.downloading = this.CsvDownloadService.downloadInProgress;
    this.eventListeners.push(
      this.$rootScope.$on('csv-download-request-completed', (): void => {
        this.downloading = this.CsvDownloadService.downloadInProgress;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Destroy part

```
 public $onDestroy() {
    while (!_.isEmpty(this.eventListeners)) {
      console.log("EventListneronDestroy");
      _.attempt(this.eventListeners.pop());
    }
  }
```